# create a jar file - Dalvik error

Tags: android, jar, executable-jar

I have an android project that contains only a .java file. This java file extends the class Services.

I am trying to build a jar file using ***** **Build Fat JAR*****.**

**I did the following:**

- right click the project -> select Fat Jar and inside the Configure Fat Jar Plug-In I've selected the OPTION: select Manifest file. With next-> finish I've managed to create the .far file.

**PROBLEMS:**

The jar icon has a red x mark in front of it. When adding the jar inside another project and when running the application (creating apk) I get the following:

**Dx trouble writing output: invalid header field. Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 3**

What am I doing wrong?
Need some help.

Thank yiu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Create a JAR from a Android project follow below steps

Project -> Properties -> Android -> Check 'Is Library' option.

Now build Project and get jar in 'bin' folder.

Comment: and if i add the library in my project , in debugging mode will i be able to step into the methods from the library I am using with F5?

Comment: It is possible to debug if source of library is linked to project.