# Export android package to jar

Tags: android, jar, package

I have a problem, I would like to export the package from the android project file. Jar and then import it into the project to continue this package meets its functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can add one project to another via Project -> Properties -> Java Build path -> Projects -> Add.

Or you can create JAR of project as mentioned in [create a jar file - Dalvik error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571639/create-a-jar-file-dalvik-error/17571760#17571760)

Answer (score 0):

Well, to export a package to a jar, right click on the package then choose the "export" option. Under `Java` choose `JAR` file. You can choose a target directory at the next screen, for ease of access, I tend to export directly into the `libs` folder of the other project that will be using this `JAR`. If you export it to the `libs` folder, right click on the `JAR` and choose `Build Path -> Add to build path`.